# Google Chrome rendering XML as text for RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, google-chrome

I have this script to generate an XML file for an RSS feed.  Works great in every browser except Chrome.  Chrome just renders the XML as text.  Something to do with `header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");` possibly?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$linkUp = "http://localhost/sites/myBlog/";

header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$rssfeed  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$rssfeed .= '<channel>';
$rssfeed .= '<title>Mytitle</title>';
$rssfeed .= '<link>' . $linkUp . '</link>';
$rssfeed .= '<description>Mydescription</description>';
$rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
$rssfeed .= '<copyright>&copy; ' . strftime('%Y') .  ' . " " . ' . $linkUp . '</copyright>';


$query = "SELECT * FROM rss";
$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $db->fetch_array($result)) {

    $rssfeed .= '<item>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $row['rss_title'] . '</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>' . $row['rss_description'] . '</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>' . $row['rss_link'] . '</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($date)) . '</pubDate>';
    $rssfeed .= '</item>';
}

$rssfeed .= '</channel>';
$rssfeed .= '</rss>';

echo $rssfeed;

?>
```

Comment: You should be escaping data when you concatenate it into XML, otherwise you may be vulnerable to the same risks as with HTML injection. `htmlspecialchars` works for XML as well as HTML. Note for `<description>` if your description is text you need to HTML-escape it *twice* as otherwise it is handled as HTML. Also, you shouldn't be using entity references like `&copy;` in an XML file as they are not predefined entities like in HTML (unless you include an RSS DOCTYPE that does define them). Use character references such as `&#169;` or simply a direct `©` ISO-8859-1 byte in preference.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you are generating XML, then use an XML library, not a template.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84) in chrome that has yet to be fixed, chrome does not display xml rss feeds with any formatting whatsoever.

Update: There is now an [RSS subscription / reader extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd) for Chrome.

Comment: Can't believe this has been an issue for over a year.

Comment: Try adding "view-source:" in front of the "http://..." URL of your RSS feed in Chrome - at least you'll see some syntax coloring of xml tags

Comment: You post this in 2009 and now it's 2015 and just came here because of this behaviour. I don't think they have plans to fix this because it's 'old' tech. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem and I used "application/xml" and it fixed it right up. Chrome doesn't like "application/rss+xml".

Comment: Didn't fix, but looks neater anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line, RSS support isnt used by "majority" of users, and as such they are only implementing it as an extension, for now. The extension is available here:
[RSS SubscriptionExtension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd)

There's a detailed discussion of this on the closing comment for the bug - you can read the developer notes here:
[Comment 149](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84#c149)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the header to `text/xml` and see if it helps:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: No luck..still renders as text.

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer here: http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/user-experience/feed-subscriptions

Comment: This will only work if your character encoding is ISO-8859-1; if you coded in notepad or something, it may be ASCII or UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

try the chrome extension "XML Tree"

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: add "view-source:{feedurl}"

Note that when the url ends with .xml and is recognized as a feed by chrome, Chrome annoyingly opens a Save File dialog. But many feed urls don't end with an extension (i.e. .xml), such as:

```
http://feeds.feedburner.com/ScottHanselman
```

At root, that url is still a regular, xml feed, but for us coders who just want to see the real xml, Chrome and the others in this case show you a human readable display of the feed (very annoying!).

So the answer to *both* of these problems is contained in the comment above given by Arne Roomann-Kurrik. He should have put it as an answer, because it works!

view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/ScottHanselman
You don't even need "http://".