# Blank Page for RSS Feed in Chrome

Tags: c#, xml, google-chrome, rss

My site have  support RSS Feed, so the xml generated by site is like the following:

[image]

So, every thing is fine in IE:
[image]

But in Chrome I get Blank page.
Where is the problem?

Does any one have any idea about this? Is there any settings in generated xml that I must correct it?
Any Suggestion?

**Update :**

I found [Google Chrome rendering XML as text for RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656574/google-chrome-rendering-xml-as-text-for-rss-feed) is [Known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84), As I understand we can not support xml format for RSS Feeds in Chrome. if I am right So what is other options? How can I support RSS for all browsers included Chrome?

And I (and clients) don't want to install any add-on on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Chrome can not parse xml file without style, so if we want to use xml format we need to use xslt file. The solution is write own xslt file and add needed path to xml file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myxsltfilepath.xslt" media="screen" ?>
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that a mis-match of protocols will also cause the issue (as I've just found)... e.g. if the .xslt has an absolute URL under http:// and the .xml is accessed via https:// Chrome will also show blank screen without any errors/warnings