# RSS feed printing XML code

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have a WordPress site which has an `RSS` Feed but when I'm checking the `RSS` feed page it shows `XML` code;

[image]

Why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers display RSS feeds in different ways, as RSS is just a standardized XML format. It looks like you're trying to view the feed in Chrome. If you try opening it in Internet Explorer, it will likely appear "normal", because IE has a built-in RSS viewer that will format the RSS XML for you.

For example, look at Wordpress' own blog in Chrome and you'll see behavior similar to your screenshot: http://wordpress.org/news/feed/

As a final troubleshooting step if it still appears as XML, you can always try the [W3C Feed Validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

Comment: thankx i have tested my link in W3C Feed Validator.
My link is Validated. and showing This is a valid RSS feed.
nOW HOW COULD I GET RID THIS PROBLEM IN CHROME.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't a solution. You can use something like http://www.FeedBurner.com, which will present your feeds in a nice way. The issue is that Chrome doesn't have a built-in RSS viewer like Safari, IE, and Firefox. See many other posts about it, including Chrome's user group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656574/google-chrome-rendering-xml-as-text-for-rss-feed
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LfDx3j4uYXw